# Decimal regular expression with zero

Tags: javascript, regex

We have a regular expression given below:

```
/[^0-9\\.()]/g
```

However, it does not accepts user to enter `0`, e.g. it says that `0.06` is invalid. I'd like to make such inputs also valid.

**All we need is the above regular expression to accept 0 (zero) too.**

Comment: Move ^ outside the square brackets or remove it.

Comment: Yes its working, however we are using it inside javascript replace function so on such inputs we are replacing blanks. We need such expression such that if user types any thing other than the above provided expression it should replace. For example , if user types abc the it should replace to blank.

Comment: Your edited regex looks fine. Are you doing something like [this](http://jsbin.com/nerenan/1/watch?js,console)?

Comment: Ok. Could you add some more code, or edit my demo? The regex must not be the problem then

Comment: I made [another demo](http://jsbin.com/nerenan/1/watch?js,output) using your code... and it seems to be working. Is there even more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Drake. The link which you provided did the trick.

```
var str = '0.05';
var newstr = str.replace(/[^0-9\.()]/g, '');
console.log(newstr);
```

Comment: You do not need to escape the `.` inside the character class.

Comment: Glad to have helped inadvertently. What was the problem?

Comment: The regular expression was fine. The way we had written the code was causing some issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex by removing the ^:

```
/[0-9.()]/g
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the same regular expression for input sanitizing and validation. You **cannot** use the same regex to do both tasks.

After sanitizing, you can add validation step like this:

```
/^\d*(?:\.\d+)*$/
```

Sample code:

```
var str = 'abc0.06abc';
var newstr = str.replace(/[^0-9.()]/g, '');
if (/^\d*(?:\.\d+)*$/.test(str) == false) {
   console.log(newstr + " is valid");  
}
else {
  console.log(newstr + " is not valid");
}
```

See [demo](http://jsbin.com/koyizuludo/1/)

Comment: ok let me check. Thanks. However we are doing it in Jquery like this $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.()]/g, ''));     . Is there any difference when we do it in Jquery and javascript?

Comment: No, the approach is still the same. You just need to run the check against another regex that checks for a decimal number validity.

Comment: Please do not forget to mark the answer that helped you most as accepted. And upvote those that proved useful to you. This is important.